# Bayesian inference on noncentrality parameters of t- and F-distributions

Tags: distributions, bayesian, chi-squared-distribution, non-central

Suppose I observe a random variable $x$ drawn from a non-central t- or F- distribution, and would like to perform inference on the non-centrality parameter. How would a Bayesian approach this problem? Are there known conjugate priors for these?

For the t-distribution I have seen some reference to LeCoutre's 'lambda-prime' distribution, but I believe this is for a non-informative prior (and I know very little about Bayesian analysis). Is there a parallel result for the F-distribution? How are these used?

Comment: Are you desiring a closed-form solution, or would you be willing to use MCMC techniques to generate a (large) sample from the posterior distribution?

Comment: I am looking for a closed-form solution. I was also curious if there was a well-developed Bayesian view of _e.g._ the frequentist t- and F-tests for regression, ANOVA, _etc._

Answer (score 2):

Both $t$ and $F$ distributions being outside exponential families, there is no conjugate distribution even in the central case (see [Bayesian Choice](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387715983), Chap. 3). You thus need to use non-conjugate priors and numerical methods like MCMC. For instance, using a flat prior on the non-centrality parameter.

As for your question on "How are these used?", I can only advise reading at least an introduction to Bayesian inference...

Comment: Note that t and F distributions are functions of random variables from exponential families.  Thus there is hope of finding conditionally conjugate priors - andrew gelman's folded t distributions for variance components in multilevel modelling is one example.

Comment: @probabilityislogic: truly, the hidden variable representations of the $t$ and $F$ distributions can rescind an exponential family setting. (I called this approach [hidden mixtures](http://webpac.lib.tku.edu.tw/lib/item;jsessionid=DB642A07AF0E853E2322BA728DC79461?id=chamo:280066) in the early 90's.) For someone with little knowledge of Bayesian analysis, this may be too involved, though.